# HashMaps and Lists

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I've made a function that reads in a text file and counts the frequency of words by using a hashmap. I've then found the out difficulty of making a function that sorts a hashmap... So after some research, i've found some code that sorts the hashmap by using sets and lists. However, the output of this function is a list, rather than a hashmap. Everything works and does exactly what i want. So my question is, what is the most efficient and effective way to take the contents of the list and put it back into a hashmap, so it can be used with the rest of my code.

**EDIT**

Okay, so i'm well aware that this can't be achieved as its not the purpose of when using a hashmap. The only reason i asked this is because i had existing code (before i had to implement changes) that outputs it to a file. This worked when using a hashmap, but now it's a list i'm a little stumped.

Cheers

Builds the hashmap

```
private static HashMap<String, Integer>  theHashMap(String inFileName) throws IOException {

    // Resets collections frequency values to zero
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : collection.entrySet()) {
        entry.setValue(0);
    }

    // Reads in the new document file to an ArrayList
    Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File(inFileName));
    ArrayList<String> file = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(textFile.hasNext()) {
        file.add(textFile.next().trim().toLowerCase());
    }

    for(String word : file) {
        Integer dict = collection.get(word);
        if (!collection.containsKey(word)) {
            collection.put(word, 1); 
        } else {
            collection.put(word, dict + 1);
        }
    }  

    textFile.close();  

    return collection;
}
```

Sorts the hashmap

```
private static List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sortTheHashMap(HashMap<String, Integer> values) {

    Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = values.entrySet();
    List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(set);
    Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>()
    {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2)
        {
            return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    } );
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:list){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" = "+entry.getValue());
    }

    return list; 
}
```

Output to file

```
    FileWriter fw;
    File fileName;

    fileName = new File("test.txt");
    fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);

    for (String word : document.getKey()) {
        String key = word.toString();
        String value = document.get(word);
        fw.write(key + " " + value + "\n\n");
    }

    fw.close()
```

Comment: A hashMap had no order, so you can't sort it. Maybe have a look at a TreeMap or a LinkedHashMap

Comment: you are not really understanding the concept of a hashmap if you want to order it. You idea of using a Hashmap to count strings makes a lot of sense, but trying to order it doesn't

Comment: @RafaelLima See latest edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java HashMaps by definition aren't sorted. It's explicitly written in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

If you want a Map sorted by its keys, use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by
>   a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which
>   constructor is used.

However, I'm not sure that a Map is really what you want. A map is used to find a value by a key. A sorted map sorts the keys, and it looks like you want to sort the **values** (number of occurrences). What if you have two words that appear the same number of times, under what key should they appear?

This is why `Collections.sort()` return a list - it sorts a given collection and puts the elements in the order you want.

Comment: Ahh, okay... This makes a lot of sense actually, thank you. The only reason i'd like to put sorted contents back into a hashmap is because i have existing code that outputs it to a text file. I've been researching online and looking at a lists documentation and from what i can see, i can't output both the key and value via list to a text file? I've included the code that outputs to a text file if you're interested.

Comment: How about using the information from the map to create instances of a custom class with a "word" and "count" field, sorting those, and then writing them to a file?

Comment: Hmm, i understand... But isn't that a little long winded? Can i not just take the strings from the list and output that to a file in the same function?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the sorted entries to a `LinkedHashMap`, they will remain sorted (as long as you don't add new keys), since `LinkedHashMap` maintains insertion order.

Given your `List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>`, you can produce the `Map` as follows:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = ...;
Map<String,Integer> map = entries.stream()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                           Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                           (v1,v2)->v1,
                                                           LinkedHashMap::new));
```

If your ordering was determined by the keys (instead of by the values), you could have used a `TreeMap` instead of `[Linked]HashMap`, which would have taken care of the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

[JAVA8 Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

```
@Test
public void convert_list_to_map_with_java8_lambda () { 

    List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>(); 
    movies.add(new Movie(1, "The Shawshank Redemption")); 
    movies.add(new Movie(2, "The Godfather")); 

    Map<Integer, Movie> mappedMovies = movies.stream().collect( 
    Collectors.toMap(Movie::getRank, (p) -> p)); 

    logger.info(mappedMovies); 

    assertTrue(mappedMovies.size() == 2); 
    assertEquals("The Shawshank Redemption", mappedMovies.get(1).getDescription()); 
}
```